# What's the word describing a person or the behaviour of a person seeking by every means, especially foul, to deny another person their lawful right

Tags: single-word-requests

The person could be an official who might be the contact point for the public to make an application for some service to which they would be entitled but who instead operates as a 'gatekeeper' and uses every means, especially dishonesty, to deny the applicant the right to pursue the application.

There is such a word. I cannot bring it to mind.

Comment: Since you've tagged this as a single word request, you should include a sample sentence demonstrating how the word would be used.

Comment: "disenfranchise" is the most legal-lite specific related term I can think of at present, though that typically refers to denial particularly of voting rights / empowerment thereof, whereby the rights might be impinged *de facto* (e.g. gerrymandering) instead of *de jure* (e.g. requiring real-estate ownership). realize thts doesn't capture your request, which has also me thinking there is a word connoting if not denoting the purposeful and more general (or specific in another use) denial (targeted or obstructive) of a legal right. "infringe" might be closer, though lacks purpose-ful connotation

Comment: "capricious" could maybe describe the behavior of the obstructor, but does not by itself denote denial of a lawfully governed if not legally guaranteed right.

Comment: Funny how nobody ever shows up here asking for our help in saying something ***nice*** about somebody else. Instead it's always about saying horrible things about something we disapprove of, even though this has never required fancy words to sting the worst.